# How can I check for word similarity from a list in JavaScript (without looping through an entire dictionary)?

Tags: javascript, regex, dictionary

I'm trying to write a spell-check script. Let's say I have a keyed list of 10 English words:

```
var wordList = {
    "moas" : "moas",
    "moat" : "moat",
    "moated" : "moated",
    "moating" : "moating",
    "moatlike" : "moatlike",
    "moats" : "moats",
    "mob" : "mob",
    "mobbed" : "mobbed",
    "mobber" : "mobber",
    "mobbers" : "mobbers",
}
```

and one misspelled word: "motelike" which I want to correct from the word list by finding the most similar word. If the closest word has a similarity above a certain threshold, I'll replace it.

I could put something together that loops through all of the words and checks each letter for a match, but that would be monstrously expensive to process when my dictionary is > 200,000 items). I think there must be a way to target the word's possible matches more efficiently than looping the whole array with the advantage of having a keyed list.

I can't think of how to go about doing this. It seems like it shouldn't be that hard, but I'm drawing a blank on how to get it done. Maybe something with regex involved?

Comment: I feel like there must be some clever way to do this.. I spent twenty minutes contemplating the task, wanting to feel the accomplishment of figuring it out on my own, but to no avail. I guess some times you just have to ask for help :P

Comment: You could try bucketing your dictionary by the starting letter of each word, although that doesn't allow mistakes in the first letter. Instead of having a dictionary for each and every misspelling, use something like the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) equation

Comment: @Bojangles I haven't finished reading yet but this is something that I was looking for thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is **fuzzy string searching**. There are many libraries for that, for example [fuzzyset.js](http://glench.github.io/fuzzyset.js/). You use it like this:

```
f = FuzzySet(['moas', 'moat', 'moated', 'moating', 'moatlike', 'moats', 'mob', 'mobbed', 'mobber', 'mobbers']);
f.get('moateb');
// returns [[0.8333333333333334, 'moated']]
// (array of pairs [score, match])
```

Of course, you can implement it yourself instead of using a library. [This wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) is about this problem.